# add a custom web part programmatically in web part page using Jquery

Tags: list, jquery

Hi We have 90 document libraries 90 different districts.

Client wants, each district user should only see their own document library.

I am getting district name from user profile (AD). I am thinking dynamically changing list view web part in one web part page based on District (instead of creating 90 web part pages).

If the coding is necessary only jQuery is allowed. Is it possible? I need help.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If there are 90 document libraries, then you can directly apply permission on those libraries to specific set of people. So other users will never see the remaining libraries

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery to showing/hiding webpart is not the best approach. To implement true security, you should create SharePoint groups for each of the districts and then add specific users into those groups.

Couple of options

1. Create separate SharePoint groups for each district. And then audience target the weparts on the page
2. Break Inheritance on the libraries. And provide unique permissions based on the user. Then use a Content Search webpart for displaying the documents.